# How to translate active_admin_comments model name in admin nav bar?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I am tried it by this way:

```
ru:        
  activerecord:
    models:
      active_admin:
        comment:
          one: Комментарий
          other: Комментарии
```

AND

```
ru:        
  activerecord:
    models:
      active_admin/comment: Комментарий
```

But nothing works

Comment: So you just want to rename it from active_admin_comments to something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ru:        
  activerecord:
    models:
      comment: Комментарий
```